# Why does http PATCH method not supported in jdk8

Tags: http, java-8

In JDK8, HttpURLConnection.java doesn't support PATCH method. But why? And how can I solve the problem if the server use PATCH method?

```
    /* valid HTTP methods */
    private static final String[] methods = {
        "GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE"
    };
```

Comment: Probably wont help you specifically, but consider upgrading to a version that is not 10 years old. These problems are obsolete with a more modern interface, such as `HttpClient` (Java 11+).

Comment: In 1997, RFC 2068 defined PATCH method. In 2013, jdk8 was born. It's difficult to understand why jdk8 doesn't support http PATCH method.

Comment: To be fair, this class existed much longer before JDK 8 already. Instead of adjusting the old legacy stuff, they probably instead focused on developing the modern variant `HttpClient`. Which has `method("PATCH", ...)`.

Comment: Your best bet, if you cant go to Java 11+, is probably to use a framework like Apache HttpClient. Thats at least what people usually used back then, before Javas own HttpClient was a thing. Or if your communication is really simple, you can also write it yourself - the basics of HTTP are actually fairly easy. But again, seriously consider upgrading. Java 8 is really old, you shouldnt be working with such old software.

Comment: The class is not final. You can extend it and override its `setRequestMethod` method, allowing more, if you want. No guarantee that the class works out of the box if you just give it PATCH like that, but you can give it a try.

Comment: "This class existed much longer before JDK 8 already". Yes, it makes sense. And it's our company use jdk8 that I use jdk8.